# Filter data based on user input after it is returned from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am retrieving a document from Firestore that looks like the following:

```
document: [
  field1: 5, 
  field2: 7, 
  field3: 2
]
```

I have a function that listens to the document and updates the table whenever there are any changes. But I want to add functionality to filter the data returned from Firebase based on a user input from a `UIPickerView`. The data is pretty small so I want to grab the data when the view is loaded and filter on the client side. I was planning on writing a `filterData` function that took in data returned from Firestore and then filter it on the client side but I was not sure where to put this in the view controller. I tried putting it after `getStats()` in `viewDidLoad()` but the tableData is empty when I add a print after `getStats()` in `viewDidLoad()`.

```swift
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    statTable.dataSource = self
    statTable.delegate = self
            
    getStats()
    
  }
    
  func getStats() {
    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
      firestoreDB
        .collection("stats")
        .document(currentUser)
        .addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
          print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } 
        else {
          if let document = documentSnapshot {
            tableData = document
          }
        }
        self.statTable.reloadData()
      }
    }
  }

  func filterData(filter) {
    
}
```

Comment: Why not inside the closure before the call to reloadData()

Comment: I thought this wouldn't work because I want to filter the data on the client side and I figured that would only be reached if data on firestore changed since it is inside of the listener. I want to the user to be able to change the filter while the data from firestore hasn't changed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, all code in your question is on the "client side". Given your question I assumed the filter was already set in another view controller but if it is happening here then you should add call the function whenever the filter changes

Comment: I guess what I mean is, where can I put the filter logic to ensure that it runs after the data is returned from firestore?

Comment: That would be in the closure.